# Operation on row of dataTable javascript is failed

Tags: javascript, html

I am using dataTable on a table to show limited entries.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#studentTable').dataTable( {
        "bSort":false,"sPaginationType":"full_numbers"
    } );

    } );
```

Now there are number of student in table. Supoose on first page 10 and than 10 and than so on.
Now each row has checkbox for student select.

Now when I select two student from page 1 and two more from other page and click on a button email to selected. than only select two students id on which page I am present.

Comment: When you say page do you mean logical table page? Otherwise if you mean web page, is your web app single page app? If not where exactly are you storing the students checked when changing pages? (the last question also stands if you have paging in your table and removing dom elements)

Comment: See. all the students are present on the page source but using js i am showing some at a time. so logically all students are present in the table and they are being selected

Comment: From your source i can tell that you are using http://datatables.net/ jquery plugin, which actually removes row dom elements when doing paging. When you check students and move back and forward do they remain checked? probably not. Please provide your html code as well.